# The relationship between the textarea and submit button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make facebook style comment post area but css is not working. What I'm trying to do. When increased the height of the `textarea` i want to `submit` button move down at the same time.  When you write a few lines in the `textarea`, you'll see the `submit` button does not go move down at the same time.

**HTML**

```
<div class="stcommenttext">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="comtextarea">
            <div class="yorumyazalani">
                <textarea name="comment" class="comment" maxlength="200" id="" rows="2" cols="50" value="Add your comment here...."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="comgonder">
                <input type="submit" value="" id="" rel="" class="comment_button wallbutton" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.comment {
    border:1px solid #fff;
    width:425px;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-family:'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    resize:none;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
.comtextarea {
    float:left;
    width:494px;
    margin-left:3px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.comtextarea textarea {
    min-height:30px;
}
.yorumyazalani {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
.comgonder {
    float:right;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
.wallbutton {
    float:left;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 32px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: white !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-image:url(https://scontent-a-fra.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/10291103_828742610487379_816788942451910142_n.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    outline:none;
}
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/JAhtp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS for the button:

```
.comgonder {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And this for the textarea:

```
.yorumyazalani {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This will make your 2 form elements inline (instead of floating them) and allow the button to be aligned based on the *bottom* of the textarea, instead of the top.

Updated Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CdxDI

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple explanation and solution.

Comment: Glad it helped, feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: @s-b dear. Can i ask you one question. `textarea` has `padding` but i can not add `padding`. Where these gaps comes and how can I get rid of these gaps ?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this in a couple of simple steps:

1. Set `position: relative;` on `.comtextarea`. Now each child can relate to it's container.
2. Set `position: absolute;` on `.comgonder`. Now you can position this element in relation to `.comtextarea`.
3. Set `bottom: 5px;` and `right: 5px;` on `.comgondor`. It now follows the right corner of `.comtextarea`.

[Codepen Fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbyHk)

Answer (score 0):

```
.comtextarea
  {
     position: relative;
  }

.comgonder
  {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
  }
```

You can change the right/bottom offsets for better spacing/alignment if you like